# Ubuntu on qnap ts-231

Tags: arm

My qnap nas is old. No support for docker and other features with native QTS. I'm looking for an alternative os. I Heard about some Ubuntu ports for arm devices but i don't know where to start.

My devices:

> CPU   Freescale™ ARM®v7 Cortex®-A9 dual-core 1.2GHz processor with Floating Point Unit and Hardware Encryption Engine
> DRAM    512MB
> Flash Memory    512MB

My goal is to intall Ubuntu server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: I have the same NAS and have the same question.

Cortex A9 is closely related to A7 powering the Raspberry Pi 2, which is a [supported platform for Ubuntu Core](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/supported-platforms). I doubt it's a drop in replacement, however.